# Turn variable value into a new variable in bash

Tags: bash, shell

I have a function defined below. Each time it runs through the array, I want it to update an existing variable (`${1}_FLAG}`). Not working as I intended it to. Basically if a new version of said package exist, set the flag to true so I can call another function.

Removed "extra" variables because people are caught up on them. What I need is to update the `HTTP_FLAG` `PHP_FLAG` and `MOD_QOS` variables when they're being looped through.

```
HTTP_FLAG=false
PHP_FLAG=false
MOD_QOS=false

PKGS=(HTTP PHP MOD_QOS);

check_new_version() {        
    # If a new version is available, download the source file
    if [ ${!check_version} != ${!current_version} ]
    then
        ...
        ...
        ${1}_FLAG=true
    fi
} 

for i in "${PKGS[@]}"
do
    check_new_version $i
done

if ${HTTP_FLAG}; then
    ...
    ...
fi
```

Comment: Where are you setting `HTTP_VER`, `HTTP_CURRENT`, `HTTP_LINK`, et. al.?

Comment: Above the script is rather long, I didn't think they would be relevant. An example would be `HTTP_LINK="http://apache.ziply.com/httpd/${HTTP_VER}"`

Comment: please edit your question to include demonstration of "Not working as I intended it to", with required output VS current output. OR use `set -vx and set +vx` to turn on/off shell debugging trace to see how each cmd/block is being processed with variable substitutions include. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need `eval`:

```
$ set -- FOO
$ FOO_FLAG=false
$ eval ${1}_FLAG=true
$ echo $FOO_FLAG
true
$
```

In `bash`, you'd like to use the `${!var}` notation, but I didn't manage to find the direct invocation that would work.  This gets close via the `var` variable, but not quite there:

```
$ var=${1}_FLAG
$ FOO_FLAG=false
$ ${!var}=true
bash: false=true: command not found
$ : ${!var}=true
$ echo $FOO_FLAG
false
$
```

Comment: That is exactly the issue I'm having.

Comment: I got around this by using `export "${1}_FLAG"=true`

Answer (score 0):

bash has [indirect parameter expansion](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), so you can do:

```
varname=${1}_LINK
value=${!varname}
```

example

```
$ foo_LINK="hello world"
$ set -- foo
$ varname=${1}_LINK
$ echo ${!varname}
hello world
```